# Using facebook Graph API to show a wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble navigating Facebook's Graph API. What I'd like to do is show a page's wall (or just the last post from that wall) on our website. I have a business manager account with only one user.

My first problem is I can't seem to find where to get a page access token to use any of the Graph commands. How do I generate a token ?

Do I need to generate the token under the user's account and not the business manager account?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: @CBroe I've definitely read through that several times, I can't find anything under my business manager account that generates one of these tokens.

Comment: Because you need to use your user account to generate the access tokens. As it is explained in the documentation

Comment: If the page is public/not access-restricted in any way, and the posts are not targeted to specific audiences, then you can use any type of access token - like your app access token. (And that can either be requested using the endpoint described in the docs - or you can just use the combination of app id and app secret connected with a pipe symbol, `app_id|app_secret`.)

Comment: in addition to all the other useful information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/